# Interpretation of descriptive statistics

Tags: correlation, descriptive-statistics

I am currently investigating whether there is a positive relationship between 2 variables. I have worked out the sample mean for both my dependent and independent variables but I am not quite sure what to comment about it because the main focus is to run the regression for the data. The 2 mean values for the 2 sets of data are similar. What kind of comment could I make to show the importance of the mean values or is working out the mean values a bit pointless when you are trying to prove there is a relationship between 2 variables?

Thanks

Comment: Regarding relationship you need to look at how well the regression fit is and how significant the correlation coefficient is. The two variable could have identical means and yet be totally unrelated to each other.

Answer (score 1):

The means of the two samples do not tell you anything about their correlation.  An appropriate descriptive statistic for this purpose would be some measurement of sample correlation (e.g., the [Pearson sample correlation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pearson_correlation_coefficient#For_a_sample)).  The sample correlation gives you a basic estimate of the correlation between the variables; a positive sample correlation is indicative of a positive relationship.

Comment: A negative correlation would be indicative of an inverse relationship. Most likely the estimate will not be zero. The issue is whether or not it is statistically significantly different from zero.